# Is there a function in R that replicates the output for regression similar to the Analysis Toolpak in Excel?

Tags: r, regression

The Summary Output for regression using the Analysis Toolpak in Excel is impressive, and I would like to replicate some of that in R. I only need to see coefficients of correlation and determination, confidence intervals, and p values (for now), and I know how to calculate the first two. Is there a function in R that does all of this automatically, or must these be calculated individually? I've seen examples using the summary() function in R that appears to do this but I'm not able to replicate the results. Any suggestions on how to proceed, including the necessary libraries, would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes there is, however, you will need to learn a little about R and how to load and reference your data.  And then be in a position to use R as you desire. As for R and regression statistics, try this web page as a starting point to learn [r-linear_regression](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_linear_regression.htm)

Comment: Also if you plan to do more in R, look up R Studio. It is a desktop more user friendly way to access and use R.

Comment: Try `fit <- lm(wt~mpg, mtcars); library(broom); tidy(fit); glance(fit); augment(fit)`

Comment: I appreciate the link to r-linear_regression and reviewed the information. I'm fairly new to R so recognize I'm missing some steps but need help understanding what those are.

Comment: I appreciate the link to r-linear_regression and reviewed the information. I'm fairly new to R so recognize I'm missing some steps but need help understanding what those are. I'm using R Studio but am new to the lm() function. The example in the link is shown using the R Console so I need to adapt that to using my data frame in R Studio. I will explain below what I've attempted so far.

Comment: My data frame is named xmasCount_Amt_df_ByCheckDate_2020 (contains data for 2020). I tried applying the lm() function as follows to the columns to be used for the X and Y variables:  lm(xmasCount_Amt_df_ByCheckDate_2020$Amount, xmasCount_Amt_df_ByCheckDate_2020$n). This produces the following error: Error in formula.default(object, env = baseenv()) : invalid formula. I'm guessing I need to define X and Y more specifically but I don't know the syntax to do that. I also need to know what library I should load before running the code.

Comment: John, can you please elaborate on your suggestion? I tried adding library(broom) and lm(Amount~n) which produced "cannot coerce class ‘"formula"’ to a data.frame". I then tried using lm(Amount,n). which produced "object 'Amount' not found". I do want to create a new data frame that contains the results. Can you please suggest how I write the code using library(broom), source file xmasCount_Amt_df_ByCheckDate_2020, identify the X column "n" and Y column "Amount" in the source file, specify how the lm() function should be written, and create a new data frame for the results? Thank you.